# Notepad++ replace with reg expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big list with links and other date in it. I want to filter out all the data and have a list with just the links.

Example of the current list:

```
32,2012-01-04 06:44:44,http://link.com/link 
33,2012-01-04 06:44:45,http://link.com/link,{Text|textext|text},http://link.com/link|http://link.com/link|http://link.com/link
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ offers find replace functionality using RegEx. You can access this feature by using Ctrl+H.

If you're actually asking for a regular expression to do this, you can use something like this to match URLs:

```regex
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

which I found [here](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls).

Additionally you can test out changes to your regex easily at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Notepad++ has a severely limited regex engine, to the extent that the given expression won't work.

Comment: Indeed. If the file is not too large, I'd just use the http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ site to make the changes you want.

Comment: The file is only 150 lines, but sometime there are ~3 links on 1 line. But I have no idea how to use gskinner or regex and all those function. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the input you provided, here's a pattern you can use on http://www.regexr.com/
You'll need to make sure the global (/g) flag is on

Expression:

```
.*?(http.*?)[,|\n]
```

Input:

```
32,2012-01-04 06:44:44,http://link.com/link1 
33,2012-01-04 06:44:45,http://link.com/link2,{Text|textext|text},http://link.com/link3|http://link.com/link4|http://link.com/link5
```

Substitution:

```
$1\n
```

Output:

```
http://link.com/link1 
http://link.com/link2
http://link.com/link3
http://link.com/link4
http://link.com/link5
```

Comment: `[,|\n]` is a character class that matches `,`  or `|` or `\n`. I guess you mean `(,|\n)` or `[,\n]`. But `(,|\R)` is better, `\R` matches `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.

Comment: @M42 I meant a literal `|`.  Some of the links are separated using `|`. Good call on the `\R` - Thanks for explaining!